# Do pictures and videos sent via the Facebook Messenger website expire?

Tags: facebook-messenger, video, images

I sent a few pictures and videos to a friend via the Facebook Messenger website.  Do pictures and videos sent via the Facebook Messenger website expire? I.e., will they disappear or will only a thumbnail will be available after a while?